# post and receive from azure

Tags: jquery, azure, chatbot

Hi all I have created a q&a chatbot in azure. That is working fine. I have then followed these instructions to test the bot in postman

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/Quickstarts/get-answer-from-knowledge-base-using-url-tool?pivots=url-test-tool-postman
```

That also works fine

I am now trying to adapt it so I can use it on a web page using jquery. My code looks like this

```
function chatBot() {
    var url = "https://myanda.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker/knowledgebases/asdf7-dd-dddd-9ddd782-ddddd/generateAnswer";
    $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: { "question": "this is my question" },
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "EndpointKey jdjdj-djkdaskj-d-dddd", 
        "Content-Type": "application/json" 
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.info(data);
    }, error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + ":" + XMLHttpRequest + ":" + errorThrown);
    }
    });
    }
```

However I get the following error

```
    {"error":{"code":12,"message":"Parameter is null","target":null,"details":null,"innerError":null}}
```

Can anyone help?

thanks

Comment: That error message is coming from the endpoint you're calling. Presumably the request data is missing some properties. Check the documentation. No one here will be able to help you with this as it's an implementation issue, not a code one.

Comment: But in Postman using the exact same parameters and values it is working.

Comment: In which case compare the request data of both to determine what's missing - don't forget to check the headers too

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer turns out to be quit simple if anyone else ever wants to do this. It seems it is not expecting the question and answer to be in a json format but just a string

```
function chatBot() {
    var url = "https://myanda.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker/knowledgebases/asdf7-dd-dddd-9ddd782-ddddd/generateAnswer";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: '{"question":"this is my question"}',
        headers: {
        "Authorization": "EndpointKey jdjdj-djkdaskj-d-dddd", 
        "Content-Type": "application/json" 
        },
        success: function (data) {
        console.info(data);
        }, error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + ":" + XMLHttpRequest + ":" + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

works great